# FaxServer Alternative for Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, object, com, coldfusion, windows-server-2008

To send a fax internally, we have been using the following Coldfusion code to create the object that handles the fax:

```
<cfobject type="COM" action="Create" name="objFaxServer" 
class="FaxServer.FaxServer.1">
```

While we are remaining on ColdFusion 8, we are moving our server to Windows Server 2008, which is a 64-bit system.  As a result, we are now unable to call COM objects, such as FaxServer, to handle such requests.  I'm looking for an internal alternative (no 3rd party like InterFax.net) but I have not been able to find one, nor any advice to handle this situation.

Any suggestions on what to use or how to internally send out faxes via coldfusion?

Comment: I wonder if .Net can still send faxes using FAXCOMEXLib under 64bit WinServer '08+.  If yes, then you can invoke the .net service from CF... but I'm not sure how fast and/or reliable it'd be.

Comment: Henry, could you provide an example of how to invoke the .net service?  I thought I had it right, having it call a .dll file in the windows system directory which I know is there, but I'm getting a file in the assembly does not exist error.  Please advise!

Comment: sorry that's not my area of expertise.  However you can google for the CF dev guide.  It has topics on how to invoke .net components.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an email to fax gateway such as [efax](http://www.efax.com.au/). This makes the whole process very simple you just send an email with the phone number in the subject field.

I know you said internally, but I think externally is better :)

Comment: I can see that Dale, the only thing is my supervisor had this happening via our server and ColdFusion before and would really want to keep it that way and not use any 3rd party applications.  I would be down for efax or something similar ONLY IF there was no other method available to achieve a coldfusion call to a FaxServer or related object to send a fax.  If there is a method to do it via 64-bit Windows Server 2008, I'm all ears.  If not, I'll be glad to know that as well.