# Sending Fax via ColdFusion & VBScript Windows Server 2008

Tags: coldfusion, vbscript, 64-bit, windows-server-2008, fax

This is related to a [previous thread I started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590534/faxserver-alternative-for-windows-server-2008), but it deals with a method that actually works.

I have created a VBScript that ColdFusion executes and sends a fax to a specific number.  The following is the VBScript I wrote, taken from a Microsoft TechNet Site:

```
Set objFaxDocument = WScript.CreateObject("FAXCOMEX.FaxDocument")
Set objFaxServer = WScript.CreateObject("FAXCOMEX.FaxServer")
Dim JobID

objFaxServer.Connect("")
objFaxDocument.Body = "C:\*PATHNAME*\testfax.pdf"
objFaxDocument.DocumentName = "My First Fax"
objFaxDocument.Priority = "2"

objFaxDocument.Recipients.Add("8885551212")

objFaxDocument.AttachFaxToReceipt = True

objFaxDocument.CoverPageType = "1"
objFaxDocument.CoverPage = "generic"
objFaxDocument.Note = "Here is the info you requested"
objFaxDocument.ReceiptAddress = "test@test.com"

objFaxDocument.Subject = "Today's fax"
objFaxDocument.Sender.Title = "Mr."
objFaxDocument.Sender.Name = "Test Man"
objFaxDocument.Sender.City = "Test City"
objFaxDocument.Sender.State = "FL"
objFaxDocument.Sender.Company = "Test Company"
objFaxDocument.Sender.Country = "USA"
objFaxDocument.Sender.Email = "test@test.com"
JobID = objFaxDocument.ConnectedSubmit(objFaxServer)
MsgBox("The Job ID is :" & JobID(0))

objFaxServer.Disconnect()
```

The following is the ColdFusion code I use to execute this vbscript:

```
<cfexecute name="C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe"
    arguments="C:\*SCRIPTPATH*\test.vbs">
</cfexecute>
```

On a machine that has Windows Server 2003, this successfully sent the document to the Windows Fax Service application, and stored the fax correctly in the outbox.  However, when I attempted this on Windows Server 2008, it does not work.  It should be noted that while the same version of ColdFusion (8) is being used, the 2008 machine is 64-bit while the 2003 is 32-bit.

This may have been answered elsewhere (if so please guide me) but I have had the hardest time with this and there are not many successful solutions out there for me to find.  I know I'm missing something but I don't know what.  Can anybody help?

Comment: Does it work when you run it at the prompt on the server? Do you get any errors messages then?

Comment: Yes.  I go to the command prompt, and execute cscript.exe followed by the path of the VBS.  It first opens the pdf document (something I need to figure out how to stop) and then once it completes the process with no errors, I see the document in the Fax Service queue.

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to answer that precisely because you don't quantify "does not work".  In what way does it not work?  Is there an error on the screen?  Is there an error in the log files anywhere?  Does the VBS get called, but does it then fail (it could be a vagary of how it's being called)?

That said, I suspect it's a case that the service account that CF is running under doesn't have permissions to access or execute the VBS, or some other resource the VBS uses.

If you login as the user CF uses, can you execute that statement from a command line?